# MongoDB updating by inserting new row

Tags: mongodb-query

This works:

```
 db.users.update( { _id:ObjectId("1234")}, { $set: { active: 1 } } )
```

because:

*If the field does not exist, $set will add a new field with the specified value, provided that the new field does not violate a type constraint.*

So active is created with value "1" and I'm happy, because that's what I wanted.

But

```
 db.users.update( { _id:ObjectId("1234")},  { $set: { profile: { active: 1 } } } )
```

This, instead of writing "active:1" as a new row inside profile, will erase all the data of "profile" and then, when 'profile' is empty, finally insert "active:1". I just lost the data of 25k users (profile.name,profile.age, etc). Could someone explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that when you did

```
db.users.update( { _id:ObjectId("1234")},  { $set: { profile: { active: 1 } } } )
```

It will update the value of `profile` field in the `user` `collection`, by replacing the content of `profile` field with `{ active: 1 }` as the behaviour you got.

To update a particular `field('active' in this case)`in a particular`document({ profile: { active: 1 } in this case)`you have to use the`dot` notation. For example:

```
db.users.update( { _id:ObjectId("1234")},  { $set: { "profile.active": 1 } } )
```

It will also do an update, but now it will `update` the `active` field of the `profile` document in the `user`collection.

**Explaination**

> The `$set` operator replaces the value of a field with the specified
>   value.
>
> If the field does not exist, $set will add a new field with the
>   specified value, provided that the new field does not violate a type
>   constraint. If you specify a dotted path for a non-existent field,
>   $set will create the embedded documents as needed to fulfill the
>   dotted path to the field.
>
> If you specify multiple field-value pairs, $set will update or create
>   each field.

For ref: "http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/"

Comment: Understood. I find the syntax unnecessarily dangerous, though. What's the key and what's the document? The documents seem to be every independent entry for every user, but, according to what you say, "active" is the key, but then what is "profile"? Another key? Do we consider "active" a key of a key (profile.active)? Or just another key. One thing is clear for me: If 'active' is a key, 'profile' can't be a key too.

Comment: In mongoDb there is a concept of **Embedded Documents** . For your case for the profile key in the document there is an embedded document {'active' : 1}. Hope now its clear!! Please refer to this link for better understanding. [data modelling mongodb](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/core/data-modeling-introduction/)

Comment: What I understand from that link: 'User' is a document, 'Profile' is a sub-document and 'active' is a embedded sub-document of 'profile' sub-document. I fail to see the 'key' part, which you removed from your answer by the way.

Comment: This "{ profile: { active: 1 } }" as a whole is a document in which the **key** is 'profile' and the **value** is another document "{ active: 1 }"(which is embedded subdocument). Now this goes on. The use of work **key** was used to explain the concept. I m so sorry if it created any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The **$set** operator *replaces* the value of a field with the specified value.

To update an embedded field, use the dot notation. When using the dot notation, enclose the whole dotted field name in quotes:

```
db.users.update( { _id:ObjectId("1234")},  { $set: { "profile.activeactive": 1 } } )
```